# PHP - is there any possible way to curl to a file containing file_put_contents, and execute successfully?

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to curl to a file containing a file_put_contents, but for some reason the file_put_contents refuses to execute, if i execute the curl file!

here is my curl code for reference :

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com/example.php");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $gradecurl = curl_exec($ch); 
     curl_close($ch);

    echo $gradecurl;

?>
```

and here's the file put contents code im using within 'example.php':

```
file_put_contents ('test.py', 'hello');
```

it works if i execute 'example.php' directly, but if i curl to it, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you currectly , you want to download and EXECUTE the php code on your server after curl the file you need to do the following:

1. Change the example.php to example.txt
2. instade of echo $gradecurl ->>> eval($gradcurl)

if i did not , let me know...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute it as php code, use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) instead of echo.

```
eval($gradecurl);
```

however, your curl code suggests you're loading this over http, which makes your code here very vulnerable to [MITM hacker attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). a hacker getting in on your lan could hijack the connection and make your server eval() execute whatever code they please. this isn't a problem if you're already connected over a secure VPN, though... just keep that in mind, there's several security issues with eval.